# Spring AOP not working with MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aspectj

I know there are lot of threads for this issue, I tried to go through all the answers but nothing worked for so far. My code doesn't throw any error, webpage is up and working but control never hits the aspect method. This is my Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @RequiresAuthenticatedUser
    public ModelAndView execute(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("welcome!");
        // generates model and view
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Aspect -

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class RequiresAuthenticatedUserAspect {
    @Around("@annotation(com.mypkg.RequiresAuthenticatedUser)")
    public void validateUser(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object[] args = proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs();
        throw new Exception("Unauthorized user");
    }    
}
```

Application context -

```
<!-- Enable AspectJ style of Spring AOP -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="false">
    <aop:include name="requiresAuthenticatedUser" />
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
```

Please help.

Comment: How is your application context loaded?

Comment: yes without any errors

Comment: No, _how_ is it loaded? By what component? Where?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. I'm passing application context xml in the JVM args

Comment: Please show how you do that. Do you have a `web.xml` or an equivalent java configuration? Post all of that.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `proxy-target-class="true"`?

Comment: If you try to intercept a method with return type `ModelAndView`, your around-advice must not return `void`, but something compatible, e.g. `ModelAndView` or `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

First, the spring and spring mvc hava different context. 
It means that spring context hold the beans  of MyController and RequiresAuthenticatedUserAspect, then spring mvc context hold the bean MyController. Take care it is different.
When you request to your server, then MyController in spring mvc context is responsible to handler this. At this time RequiresAuthenticatedUserAspect  cut the MyController in spring context. So the aspect will never work.

So I think you should check in your dispatcher-servlert.xml(may be other name) , you should scan the package RequiresAuthenticatedUserAspect in and be careful you should scan component Annotation also.